# some problem with iOS 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, crash

I've been developing an app with MacBook Pro (MBP) so far. Last week one of my friends gave me new macbook air 11"(MBA). so Now I can test my code with more than one machine with the same version of developing tools - Both machine has Xcode (3.2.5) and iOS SDK 4.2.1).

After some point my app starts get terminated suddenly(iPhone sumulator), and I was using MBP.

I got no error message whatsoever. it just stops. I reckon the crash comes from dealing with memory, like 'release'/ 'double-release'. (I'm not 100% sure though). Anyway I thought there must be some mistake within my code for sure.

*-Confusion starts from this part.-*

**With my MBA, on the other hand, I don'y see any crash.** It just works fine. There is nothing different between MBA & MBP except the h/w specifications. Same code, same versions of XCode and iOS SDK.

Is the fact that no crash at MBA suggesting that I have to look 
somewhere else than the code itself?

I red some article and Q&As on iOS4.2.1 and XCode 3.2.5 that the most recent version of XCode doesn't recognize the iOS 4.2.1 since the 4.2.1 came out later the 3.2.5. Is it the reason?

I have no idea at this moment what should be the next move.

thanks

-EDIT----------
I test my app with iPhone 3GS 32G. (S/w version 4.2.1) and got this error message.

> Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
>   warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

Comment: Show us your code. (Specifically, show us the code where the stack trace says you crashed.)

Comment: thanks.can you tell me briefly how to check stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please please test your code on real iDevices. And by saying iDevices I mean iPod Touch/iPhone/iPad, not MBP/MBA.

Memory related crashes can be random at a certain extent. And a crash on the simulator would very likely lead to a corresponding crash on a real iDevice. To locate and fix such crashes, please test them on real iDevices.

btw, since you said it might be a memory related bug. I suggest you turn on NSZombieEnabled and see what's wrong with your code's memory management.

Comment: from testing with iPhone device I realized something that didn't with simulator (eg. the actual picture size taken with iphone built-in camera and problems from it...). thanks for good guidance diwup.